# JQuery UI position() issue with a div within a div containing spans

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position, html

I am still new to JQuery UI. I want to align a `<div>` contain links (implemented as `<span>`) within another `<div>`. Here is the `<div>` definition in my HTML:

```
<div id='TOP'>
    <div id='TOP_LEFT'><img src="images/Logo_150x50.png"></div>
    <div id='TOP_MID'><select id="ffonts"></select></div>
    <div id='TOP_RIGHT'>
        <div id="LOGIN_LINKS">
            <span id="login">Login</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span id="registr">Registration</span><br />
            <span id="forgotpwd">Forgot Password</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span id="logout">Logout</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use the position() method as following (within document-ready):

```
$("#"+LOGIN_LINKS).position({
    my: "center bottom",
    at: "center bottom",
    of: "#"+TOP_RIGHT
});
```

but my links are not aligned at the bottom.

[image]

Why? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

After performing more tests, this issue does not happen when I put `<br />` after each span:

```
<div id="LOGIN_LINKS">
    <span id="login">Login</span><br />
    <span id="registr">Regist</span><br />
    <span id="forgotpwd">Forgot Password</span>
    <!-- span id="logout">Logout</span -->
</div>
```

[image]

It seems like a bug to me !!!

Comment: Could you post a http://jsfiddle.net example of the issue?

Comment: I have logged an issue too: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7819#trac-add-comment

Comment: jquery.position() only returns the position of the element in regards to the parent. it doesn't change the position. http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: @Gary.S Please check http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position

Comment: my mistake, didnt realize it was jquery UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there were a few issues with the jsfiddle posted but here is a working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/xb4Rf/1/

Basically the main issue i saw was that the container (TOP_RIGHT) didn't have a height so it was already at the bottom. Changing the height moves the children as expected. If you want to cascade the code that seems more complicated than just adding breaks but could be done.

Comment: Ok, I have managed to make it work like I want it too: http://jsfiddle.net/xb4Rf/5/. If only the doc had made this width or height requirement explicit...